# How to set minimum TLS on Azure Storage Account using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am in the process of creating a template for provisioning azure resources using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent C# library.

```
IAzure azure = Azure.Authenticate("./authfile.txt").WithDefaultSubscription();
var sa = await azure.StorageAccounts.Define(StorageAccount)
    .WithRegion(Region.USCentral)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(ResourceGroup)
    .WithBlobEncryption()
    .WithGeneralPurposeAccountKindV2()
    .WithFileEncryption()
    .WithOnlyHttpsTraffic()
    .WithSku(StorageAccountSkuType.Standard_LRS)
    .WithHnsEnabled(true)
    .CreateAsync();
```

I would like my storage accounts to have a minimum of TLS1.2, although I'm having trouble finding method for setting the required TLS version here.

How do I go about creating the TLS1.2 requirement here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in Fluent API, please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/556).

You can consider using the non-fluent sdk: [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage/).

For example:

```
        var storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClient(azureCredentials)
        {
          SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
        };


        var storageAccountCreateParameters = new StorageAccountCreateParameters
        {
            //set the tls here.
            MinimumTlsVersion = "TLS1_2"

            //other settings.
        };

        await storageManagementClient.StorageAccounts.CreateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, storageAccountCreateParameters);
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I was digging through the repo for hours looking for the answer. Glad to know that my search is over :p

Comment: Has the Azure Fluent Api been updated to include this functionality yet?
If not, will there be plans to?